# Python Pandas - Listing Specific Column Items Horizontally

Tags: python, pandas

Search yielded no results, so here I am!
Using Python + Pandas, I am able to import a spreadsheet. Is there a way to reformat my table from looking like this:

```
Name    | ID  | Shirt Color
Jim     | 001 | White
Michael | 002 | Green
Michael | 002 | Blue
Pam     | 003 | Pink
Jim     | 001 | Orange
Jim     | 001 | White (notice the duplicate counted separately)
```

into this?

```
Name    | ID  | Shirt Color 1 | Shirt Color 2 | Shirt Color 3 |
Jim     | 001 |     White     |   Orange      |     White     |
Michael | 002 |     Green     |   Blue        |               |
Pam     | 003 |     Pink      |               |               |
```

Im really lost as to what to call upon with Pandas to make this happen. Any help would be fantastic! I appreciate you!

I was able to use nunique to get the "count" of different shirts worn but not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need create a additional key with `cumcount` , then it become a `pivot` problem

```
df['key']=df.groupby('Name').cumcount()+1
s=df.pivot_table(index=['Name','ID'],columns='key',values='Shirt Color',aggfunc='first').\
       add_prefix('ShirtColor_').reset_index()

key     Name  ID ShirtColor_1 ShirtColor_2 ShirtColor_3
0        Jim   1        White       Orange        White
1    Michael   2        Green         Blue          NaN
2        Pam   3         Pink          NaN          NaN
```

Comment: So I gave this a shot and I think I might have too much data. I'm getting this as the final return when I try to write this to the excel file: PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\alexn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\openpyxl._ooljlh9' How do I free up the process?

Comment: @BigSecret did you get the result in panda? if so that is write xls problem , how about try to do `s.to_csv('your.csv')`

Comment: @BigSecret also , this is all I can do , try to match your expected output. If this match , would you like consider up-vote and accept ?

Comment: I used s.to_excel(pd.ExcelWriter(),index=False). Trying CSV now.

Comment: @BigSecret in your case,since you do not have the formated output,  csv and excel not much different ,I will try with csv store the data :-)

Comment: Also, outside of writing the data - the columns i'm getting are "ShirtColor_2410". It looks like its counting all the items :(

Comment: @BigSecret kindly check with your sample data and your expected output . I can only do is match what your expected output.

Comment: Big True. Loading in a sample sheet with this example yielded the results. I wonder what is causing my massive dataset to have this happen?

Comment: @BigSecret kindly check Name are same, or we should build the key with groupby('ID')

Comment: got it bro! Thank you very much. I had some reorganizing of the columns using Pandas, and I think that affected how the data was viewed. I ran this formula BEFORE adjusting the columns and such - and it worked!!! Thank you sir. Hats off to you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218061/discussion-between-big-secret-and-yoben-s).